# Declaration merging and aliasing not working together

Tags: node.js, express, intellij-idea, typescript, webstorm

I recently started converting my node.js/express application to typescript.

It is working great so far, but there are some things I am not sure of:

I noticed that in the [sample project by Microsoft](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScriptSamples/tree/master/imageboard), they are inconsistent with their typing.

app.ts

```
app.get('/findImages', function(req, res) {
    // ...
}
```

routes/index.ts

```
export function index(req: express.Request, res: express.Response) {
    // ....
};
```

As you can see they are sometimes defining types, sometimes not. I noticed that there is no IntelliSense in the first case, but this might also be an issue of IntelliJ. What would be the best practice here?

At first I thought I would just type everything, but then I noticed another odd behaviour:

app.ts

```
/// <reference path="connect-flash/connect-flash.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="express-session/express-session.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="express/express.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="passport/passport.d.ts" />

import express = require('express');
import session = require('express-session');
import passport = require('passport');
import flash = require('connect-flash');

var app: express.Express = express();

// Express without capital letter
route.get('/', function (req: express.Request, res: express.Response): void {
    req.flash('message');       // no IntelliSense
    var session = req.session;  // no IntelliSense
    var ip = req.ip;            // works
    var test = req.params.test; // works
});

// Express with capital letter
route.get('/', function (req: Express.Request, res: Express.Response): void {
    req.flash('message');       // works
    var session = req.session;  // works
    var ip = req.ip;            // no IntelliSense; compile error TS2339
    var test = req.params.test; // no IntelliSense; compile error TS2339
});
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
Error:(54, 22) TS2339: Property 'ip' does not exist on type 'Request'.
Error:(55, 24) TS2339: Property 'params' does not exist on type 'Request'.
```

I was looking through the definition files and noticed that there are apparently two different ways to define a module:

express.d.ts

```
declare module Express {...}
declare module "express" {...}
```

I tried multiple combinations of upper and lower case (also in the other definition files) with no success.

It seems that there are two separate definitions of the express module. The first one is also present in other modules such as `express-session.d.ts` or `connect-flash.d.ts`, and they are merged together correctly. But there seems to be a problem with the upper and lower case difference in the `express.d.ts` file. Is there a way to merge them?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As you can see they are sometimes defining types, sometimes not. I noticed that there is no IntelliSense in the first case, but this might also be an issue of IntelliJ. What would be the best practice here

I try to be explicit everywhere. But you can avoid this if typescript can infer it for you.

> I am getting the following errors:

If `ip` is a part of the express request then that's just an omission in the `express.d.ts` that needs to be fixed.

> noticed that there are apparently two different ways to define a module:

These the two *different* kind of modules. `declare module foo` means that is a global variable `foo` available. `declare module "foo"` means you can do `import foo = require('foo')`.

> But there seems to be a problem with the upper and lower case difference in the express.d.ts file. Is there a way to merge them

They should all have the same case.

Comment: Ah, that explains a lot already. I just noticed that the "Express with capital letter" version works if I change the import to `import Express = require('express');`. Thanks!